# How can i get the original file name using UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidocument, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I need to know the type of file that I want to import.
I can find out the type from the file name

for PHAsset you can use the following method:

```
Attachment *attachment = [[Attachment alloc] init];
                         attachment.assetIdentifierInternal = asset.localIdentifier;
                         attachment.descriptionInfo = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
                         attachment.isPhoto = YES;
                         attachment.isDocument = NO;

 NSArray *resources = [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:asset];
 NSString *fileName = ((PHAssetResource *)resources[0]).originalFilename;
  attachment.format = [fileName pathExtension];
```

is there anything similar for DocumentPicker?

descriptInfo shows without problems. name - nil.

Setter for name:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {

_name = name;

self.format = [name pathExtension];

CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef) self.format;
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

self.isPhoto = UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage);
self.isDocument = UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeData); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little searching, I found the solution myself.
Name and format is easy to track by URL. Like This

```
    attachment.fileUrlInternal = url;
    attachment.format = [attachment.fileUrlInternal pathExtension];
    attachment.name = url.lastPathComponent;
```